# Removing triviality from functional dependencies

Tags: database, database-schema, functional-dependencies

For a relation schema R=(A,B,C,D,E,G,H,I)

If there is the FD GHB --> AB, can I remove B from both sides, since B --> B is trivial, giving me GH --> A?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can remove B from the right side, getting the functional dependency GHB -> A. But all three of GHB are needed to determine A.